# Multiple select LOV in an af:query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have a jsf page that includes a research bar. The af:query which is based on a query in the research bar includes a LOV that is multiple select (Supports multiple value selection). When i choose all the values (All) in the LOV, the query because slow. The other fields work perfectly.
This makes the screen slow for the coming queries also even if i don't choose any value from this multi- select LOV.

**How can I solve this problem?**

Thank you a lot in advance for your help!

The query runs at 1 sec (to visualise the screen) while with the LOV the page needs around 20 seconds to be ready.
The latency is only reproduce-able if around 88 records are found in the LOV.

The problem is not from the SQL query since it is fast when run alone.
The problem is on oracle 11g and oracle 12c.

I reproduced the latency with the SCOTT database. (empl and dept tables where the LOV is the dept name).

**Image of EMPL and DEPT**

[image: Screen shot]

In the first query I choose the "ALL" in the LOV. Everything works perfectly. The second time whatever i choose, it takes a lot of time.
[EmpVoCriteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYsn5.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also can you provide the sql query in your view criteria right panel.

Comment: @AhmadMaleki Is the example enough?

Comment: @Cedric In the example I added the sql query is just a select from table EMPL. and the lov is based on the table DEPT. The latency is only reproduce-able if around 88 records are found in the LOV.

Comment: You need to provide the sql query in your EmpVOCriteria view criteria right panel trust me ;)

Comment: @Cedric In the view criteria right panel there is no query because we only have in the criteria (deptNo = ? and EmpNo = ?). At runtime, the query is:
SELECT EmpEO.COMM, EmpEO.DEPTNO, EmpEO.EMPNO, EmpEO.ENAME, EmpEO.HIREDATE, EmpEO.JOB, EmpEO.MGR, EmpEO.SAL FROM SCOTT.EMP EmpEO WHERE (((EmpEO.DEPTNO IN (1, 2, 3, ....,86,87,88))));
The query in PLSQL takes 0.031 seconds to fetch 14 rows.